# Do we have recipe for AWS SDK1 to SDK2 migration

Tags: openrewrite

As Java-17 onwards AWS SDK-1 is not fully supported. Do we have already recipe for SDK1 to SDK2 migration or any plan to have it in coming weeks?

Answer (score 0):

No, there are definitely no such recipes in the [OpenRewrite GitHub organization](https://github.com/openrewrite) and also no external recipes which I am aware of. But this could definitely be interesting and I am sure that any such contributions would get accepted.

There is a [Java 17 upgrade recipe](https://docs.openrewrite.org/recipes/java/migrate/upgradetojava17), but I understand that this isn't exactly what you are looking for.